# Derivative of a scalar quantity involving inverse and Kronecker product

Tags: derivatives, inverse, kronecker-product

How can we compute the derivative of the following quantity with respect to $\bf{\Sigma}$?

$$
\phi = {\bf{x}}^\top({\bf \Sigma^{-1}\otimes I){\bf x}}
$$

Edit: I have tried to solve this problem by referring to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2807505/derivative-of-the-trace-of-a-quantity-involving-kronecker-product).

$$
\phi = \text{tr}({\bf xx}^\top({\bf \Sigma}^{-1} \otimes {\bf I})).
$$

Now I need to find a factorization of ${\bf xx}^\top = {\bf A} \otimes {\bf B}$. I can factorize it as ${\bf x}^\top \otimes {\bf x}$, but this doesn't agree with the dimension of ${\bf \Sigma}$ and the identity matrix to simplify the problem further. So I am not sure how to proceed this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\l{\left}
\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\r{\right}
\def\lr#1{\l(#1\r)}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
$For typing convenience, define the matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
S &= \Sigma &\in\R{n\times n} \\
X &= xx^T \quad&\in\R{np\times np}
}$$
Let's also use a colon as a convenient product notation for the trace, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; {\rm Tr}(AB^T) \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F\\
}$$
Write the function using the above notation
$$\phi = X:\lr{S^{-1}\otimes I_p}$$
Let $\{e_k\}$ denote the $k^{th}$ column of $I_p$ and define their block-matrix analogs
$$\eqalign{
E_k &= (I_n\otimes e_k) \;\in\; \R{pn\times n} \\
}$$
Note that
$$\eqalign{
\sum_{k=1}^p E_kE_k^T
 &= \sum_{k=1}^p \lr{I_n\otimes e_k}\lr{I_n\otimes e_k}^T \\
 &= (I_n\,I_n^T)\otimes\lr{\sum_{k=1}^p e_ke_k^T} \\
 &= I_n\otimes I_p \\&= I_{np} \\
}$$
Now expand the cost function
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \lr{I_{np}\,X\,I_{np}}:\lr{S^{-1}\otimes I_p} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^p\sum_{k=1}^p \lr{E_iE_i^T}X\lr{E_kE_k^T}:\lr{S^{-1}\otimes I_p} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^p\sum_{k=1}^p \lr{E_i^T\,X\,E_k}:E_i^T\lr{S^{-1}\otimes I_p}E_k \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^p\sum_{k=1}^p \lr{E_i^T\,X\,E_k}:\lr{I_n\otimes e_i^T}\lr{S^{-1}\otimes I_p}\lr{I_n\otimes e_k} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^p\sum_{k=1}^p \lr{E_i^T\,X\,E_k}:S^{-1}\otimes\lr{e_i^Te_k} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^p\sum_{k=1}^p \lr{E_i^T\,X\,E_k}:S^{-1}\delta_{ik} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^p \lr{E_k^T\,X\,E_k}:S^{-1} \\
&\equiv Y:S^{-1} \\
}$$
Now that the independent variable has been isolated on the RHS, the rest of the derivation is a breeze.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= Y:S^{-1} \\
d\phi &= Y:dS^{-1} \\
 &= Y:\lr{-S^{-1}\,dS\,S^{-1}} \\
 &= -S^{-T}YS^{-T}:dS \\
\grad{\phi}{S} &= -S^{-T}YS^{-T} \\
}$$
If $S$ is symmetric, then this can be simplified a bit
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\phi}{S} &= -S^{-1}YS^{-1}\quad\quad\quad \\\\
}$$

---

**NB:** $\;$ The properties of the underlying trace function allow us to rearrange the terms in a colon product in a number of different ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
A:BC &= B^TA:C &= AC^T:B \\
A:B &= B:A \\
}$$